# Formik: target is undefined when passing Material UI Date Picker as prop to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm trying to create a reusable component. where I am passing the form fields as prop. when I click on datepicker field. I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: target is undefined

How can I fix this?

Here's how my input component looks like:

```
import { useField } from 'formik';
import { DatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

export const DatePickerField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);

  return (
    <DatePicker label={label} fullWidth {...field} {...props} />
  );
};
```

Here's how the reusable component looks like:

```
import { Form } from 'formik'

export const ReusableComp = ({ fields }) => (
  <Form noValidate>
      {fields}
  </Form>
)
```

Here's where I am using this component:

```
export const App = () => (
    <ReusableComp fields={
      <div className='mb-3'>
        <DateTimePickerField
          label='Start DateTime'
          name='start_date_time'
        />
      </div>
    } />
)
```

Result of `console.log(fields)`

[image]

Comment: what are the "props" values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lots of research and thanks @Rosen Tsankov for pointing my attention to the `onChange` function.

I have seen questions about the same error on SO which are not answered. so this may help them and anyone in future facing this error.

As @Rosen Tsankov have said the material ui `DatePicker` component returns the date value as the first argument of the `onChange` function.

the `field` returned from `useField` have the following: `name`, `value`, `onChange`, `onBlur`.

the `onChange` function returned from `useField` expects the first argument to be an event which in this case is the date value. that's why we get the error:

> TypeError: target is undefined

Because formik is trying to access `target` property and date has no property `target`. something like this `date.target` and this is `undefined`

so here's how I have fixed it. instead of spreading the field. I have added name and value from `field` to DatePicker. then I have used the `setFieldValue` from formik to manually update the input value like so.

```
import { DatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

export const DatePickerField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <DatePicker
      fullWidth
      {...props}
      label={label}
      name={field.name}
      value={field.value}
      helperText={meta.error}
      error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
      onChange={(value) => setFieldValue(field.name, value)}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was using the Material UI DesktopDatePicker (with Typescript), and defining the onChange prop like this solved it:

```
onChange={(value): void => {
    formik.setFieldValue("dueDate", value);
}}
```

You have to replace "dueDate" with your formik value name.

Answer (score 3):

DatePicker expects `onChange((date) => ...) but you are passing formik handler wich expects onChange((event) => ....)`

Comment: Can you share documentation link? where this mentioned. so I can read more about it. try to fix the error

Comment: passing formik handler to DatePicker  ?

Comment: console.log(field) and paste it here

Comment: Hi sorry missed your comment. was asleep already. updated the question